# Getting started with the sport of competitive programming

Tags: computer-science-theory

How do you get started with competitive programming and get well versed with various topics in it ?
What all things you can do ?
Get started directly or do some concepts first.

Comment: This video is worth watching: https://youtu.be/y7169jEvb-Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very popular question on Quora, but is generally considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. The best way to use SO for competitive programming advice is to ask specific questions about problems you're having when coding a solution. For example, you might ask how a language feature works. Often you'll find that the question has already been asked.

Here are the 108+ Quora answers to your question: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-become-a-competitive-programmer

The summary answer is: Get started solving problems. If you have any programming background, which I'm sure you do since you're asking this question, you'll get more benefit from just starting rather than reading a lot first. When you get stuck on something, that's the time to read books or online resources.

If you're having trouble deciding what to start on, here's a suggestion from my blog of how I would get started: http://www.redgreencode.com/about-project-462/

Comment: Thanks.. This is helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents...
Best option is to get registered at the following coding sites..
+ [topcoder.com](http://topcoder.com)
+ [codechef.com](http://codechef.com)
+ [hackerrank.com](http://hackerrank.com)

And, while you hack code here, you can build upon your programming foundation by learning more on
+ Data structures
+ Algorithms
+ Operating system concepts
+ Networking concepts and more ...

You could also start looking at the following books in this area...
+ [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848000693)
+ [Programming Challenges: The Programming Contest Training Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638)
+ [Competitive Programming 2](http://www.lulu.com/shop/steven-halim/competitive-programming-2/paperback/product-16377304.html)

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to get registered with a Competitive Programming site if you know how to write simple codes in a particular programming language and solve the basic problems(the ones which does not require algorithms or require basic ones).

My suggestion on the choice of site is:-

1)**HackerRank**:-https://www.hackerrank.com/

Problems are well categorized here.Practice the questions marked 'easy' here followed by a few 'medium' ones.Complete the '**30 Days of Coding Challenge**' that would give you a good basic idea of the Java language.Also, **check other's code and the editorial** even if your code passes all the test cases.

2)**SPOJ**:-

Practice the problems categorized under '**ad-hoc**' here.Start by solving the problems which are solved by most people...usually they will be easier.

3)Start implementing basic(or standard) algorithms. It is suggested to read them from **Topcoder tutorials** or **Introduction to algorithms**.Also, follow a standard book along with it.Now, practice problems based on those algorithms until you get familiar with them.

4)After you get acquainted with the most common algorithms **start competing in coding challenges**.**Practice makes you better**. Try to solve problems from previous contests. Solve as many problem A-s as you can **until they give you some trouble**.  Then move on to B, then C etc.

Hope it helps :)

P.S. **Also check the following answer on Quora**:-

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-strategy-to-improve-my-skills-in-competitive-programming-in-2-3-months/answer/Sachin-Gupta-6?srid=4gZ6