# Platform to practice basic algorithms through real life problems?

Tags: algorithm

I want to start competitive programming but the problem is I do not have much practice to solve the problems in given time.

Because competitive coding at least requires the knowledge of algorithms so, I want  to practice some basic algorithms to start.

Can anyone tell me some of the platforms where I can practice the basic algorithms through the real world problems?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31493935/3160529

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that question does not relate to the practice platforms.

Comment: Not sure about the real world problems but if you want to practice algorithms check [this](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/48877/data-structures-and-algorithms) out. It contains an extensive list of algorithms, data structures, their explanations and related programming problems.

Comment: that's nice thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should practice on the same platform where you want to start competitive programming.

I refer to this website https://www.hackerrank.com for practice.